# How to find the surrounding area 25 miles using latitude & longitude from the current user location

Tags: c#, math

I found Haversine Formula in C# is there any other method better than this.

```
public double HaversineDistance(LatLng pos1, LatLng pos2, DistanceUnit unit)
    {
        double R = (unit == DistanceUnit.Miles) ? 3960 : 6371;
        var lat = (pos2.Latitude - pos1.Latitude).ToRadians();
        var lng = (pos2.Longitude - pos1.Longitude).ToRadians();
        var h1 = Math.Sin(lat / 2) * Math.Sin(lat / 2) +
                      Math.Cos(pos1.Latitude.ToRadians()) * Math.Cos(pos2.Latitude.ToRadians()) *
                      Math.Sin(lng / 2) * Math.Sin(lng / 2);
        var h2 = 2 * Math.Asin(Math.Min(1, Math.Sqrt(h1)));
        return R * h2;
    }
```

Comment: What is wrong with the above formula?  Why are you looking for a "better" solution.  If you have a reason to replace it then express that reason.

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?  Faster?  More accurate? both?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it is a matter of what you want to do with it.  My guess is that you are trying to calculate distance based on a ZIP (Post) code and you want to know if pos2  is within x distance of pos1.

What you first need to understand is that (unless you have some awesome Geo Spatial data to work with) all calculations do not generally take into account elevation or any other topographical attributes of the given area so your calculations won't be exact.  Further these calculations are "as the crow flies" which means point x to point y is a straight line so while point y may lie within 25 miles of central point x it may actually be 30 miles to travel from central point x to point y.

That being said the Haversine Formula is your best bet unless you are calculating small distances (< ~12 miles) in which case you could use Pythagorean's theorem which is expressed as:

d = sqrt((X2 - X1)^2 + (Y2 - Y1)^2)

Where X and Y are your coordinates, obviously.  This is much faster but is far less accurate especially as distance increases.

The Haversine Formula is slow especially if you are repeated calling it but I am unaware of any faster methods for calculating distance based on this formula.